# RIchfaces 3.2 - Session issue

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, richfaces, wildfly-8

I am using richfaces 3.2.0 SR1 with wildfly in my application and facing issue of login with different browsers.
The issue is 1st i login with a particular credentials to my web-application using firefox browser it shows me HOME page which is correct, without getting logout from firefox i try to login with same credentials using chrome browser at this moment i have deleted the session of previous logged in user and created new session for new user but this time it doesn't takes me to HOME page.
 Guide me if any thing i have to add in web-xml or int relation to session.

Comment: "*without getting logout from firefox i try to login with same credentials using chrome browser at this moment i have deleted the session of previous logged in user and created new session for new user but this time it doesn't takes me to HOME page*". How do you "*delete the session of previous logged in user*"? Does it happen unexpectedly or you want it to happen deliberately (no you should not)? Those two different browsers are two different clients and do not share the same session. They live in their own session - the same way the browser of yours and mine use their own session.

Comment: You should be using Spring but not Spring MVC, by the way.